# Why dot is used in sql joins?

Tags: sql, join

In SQL join why we are using `tablename.column_name` whereas in others we use only the column name why dot is used in SQL joins ?

Comment: because we are joining two table, so there has to be specified which table it is

Comment: cause multiple table might have same column name, need to identify which column that you actually referring

Comment: This would be a much better question if you gave an example query with the syntax which confuses you in it!

Comment: because it is best practice and gives you clarity and avoids confusion for SQL to figure out which field of which table you are referring to!

Comment: Btw, `tablename.column_name` is not necessarily used in joins alone. It can be used anywhere. It can also be used as `table_alias_name.column_name`

Answer (score 2):

You only have to use `tablename.column_name` if the column name exists in multiple tables in the `JOIN`. It needs to know which table's column you're referring to.

If the column name is unambiguous, you can just write `column_name`. But some programmers prefer to be consistent and use the explicit form all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have two tables: Clients and Addresses.

- Clients table has the columns: ID, Name, AddressId
- Addresses table has these: ID, AddressField1, AddressField2

(Now it is unlikely, but to show you what I mean) Your coworker creates a query like this:

```
 SELECT ID
 FROM Clients C
 JOIN Addresses A
 ON A.ID = C.AddressId
```

If you look at it, can you determine which ID he meant to fetch?
Neither can SQL, that is why you have to define with table names or aliases.

If he would to do this

```
 SELECT Name
 FROM Clients C
 JOIN Addresses A
 ON A.ID = C.AddressId
```

You could easily tell which "Name" he is looking for as there is only one column with that name in this context.

Answer (score 0):

It is used to resolve ambiguity if the two tables have the same column name. So lets take an example say you have two tables employee and department and both have a an id column in it.

And if you want to join both the tables using the id field. Then since the id field is ambiguous then you have to write the table name like this:

```
select * from emp inner join departement on emp.id = departement.id
```

even if you want to get some specific columns from the two tables while you are joining then also you can use the tablename.column name syntax

```
select emp.name, departement.name 
from emp inner join departement on emp.id = departement.id
```

Answer (score 0):

It is best practice to use and gives you clarity and avoids confusion for SQL to figure out which field of which table you are referring to!

Btw, `tablename.column_name` is not necessarily used in joins alone. It can be used anywhere. It can also be used as `table_alias_name.column_name`

Example:

```
TABLEA : EMP_ID, NAME, ADDRESS
TABLEB : EMP_ID, EMP_NAME, PHONE_NUMBER, MOBILE_NUMBER
```

* *`NAME` and `EMP_NAME` has same value*

Your query:

```
1. Below will cause error, since it does not know if EMP_ID belongs to TABLEA or TABLE B
SELECT EMP_ID , NAME, PHONE_NUMBER FROM TABLEA, TABLEB


2. Below queries will NOT cause error 
SELECT TABLEA.EMP_ID , NAME, PHONE_NUMBER FROM TABLEA, TABLEB;
SELECT A.EMP_ID, NAME, PHONE_NUMBER FROM TABLEA A, TABLEB B;

-- Below would be recommended best practice to use for referring to variables:
SELECT A.EMP_ID, A.NAME, B.PHONE_NUMBER FROM TABLEA A, TABLEB B;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.` in sql is used to relate the column name with the table. for example there are two tables as `Employee` and `salary` and there would be a common column as `ID` which is used to query to select the salary of a employee and output the `salary` and `name` but not `ID`.

To do this we use the below query

```
SELECT Employee.name, salary.salary
FROM Employee
INNER JOIN salary
ON Employee.ID=salary.ID;
```

here the `.` in first line is used to select which column of which table and the `.` in last line is used to check the `ID` in  both the tables, and those table names are given before `.`

If the last line is like below.

```
ON ID=ID;
```

there would be a conflict/confusion due to which there would be error triggered.

cheers!

Rakesh